# emulator: ERROR: A snapshot operation for 'Nexus_4_API_27' is pending and timeout has expired. Exiting

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

```
emulator: ERROR: A snapshot operation for 'Nexus_4_API_27' is pending and timeout has expired. Exiting...
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to open emulator from **command-line** with this bellow command.

```
anjan@anjan-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~/Android/Sdk/emulator$ ./emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_27
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: yes I have solved it to restarting emulator.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo rm ~/.android/avd/<your-device-name>.avd/*.lock
```

This command will remove files like:

- ~/.android/avd/your-device/hardware-qemu.ini.lock
- ~/.android/avd/your-device/multiinstance.lock
- ~/.android/avd/your-device/snapshot.lock.lock

Comment: My disk space was low. After running this command, it started giving this error:
`1:43 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 5981.429688 MB at /home/sufian/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_26.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.`. I just had to make some space and then it was gone. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is caused be the lock file generated by the boot which reside in the folder = **.android/avd/{yourDeviceName}**.

we can delete by using **sudo rm snapshot.lock.lock** command.

[image]

Then cold booting the device again ,solves the issue.

Comment: rm ~/.android/avd/{yourDeviceName}/hardware-qemu.ini.lock could also be deleted

Comment: Please explain your command so other users can understand its functionality. Don't use images links that could be broken in the future Thanks!

Comment: Feedback noted. :) Ok.This is caused by a lock file that resides in avd folder in home/.android.  Removing the lock file and restarting the emulator will solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

If you have android studio installed (Obviously) just open the AVD Manager, select the device and choose 'Stop' by using the right click. Then the device will be released.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error in ubuntu and  the fix was to change the owner of my $HOME/.android folder into my current user. ie.

```
sudo chown -R [username] $HOME/.android
```

Comment: If this was caused by a permissions issue in Unix (it was for me as well), you can also type `sudo` before the emulator command

Answer (score 2):

- Click on the 'down arrow' for the selected device from the device manager
- Show on desk
- hardware-qemu.ini.lock
- multiinstance.lock
- snapshot.lock.lock
- Delete this three files

Enjoy!!
It works with macOS don't know about windows

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME/.android`

then

`./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28`

above command will do the trick!

If it get below error!

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm)
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Linux:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
```

try with

`sudo ./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28`

It worked for me!